# Release file\folder lock when using drag\drop onto control

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to loop through a list of files to get the path and filename.
These files are dragged onto a datagrid:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DragDrop

Dim filenames As String() = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())

    For Each File In filenames
        If Array.IndexOf(SupportedFormats, System.IO.Path.GetExtension(File)) <> -1 Then
            Frm = New FormRestore(ServerName, File)
            Frm.Show()

            While Frm.Visible
                Application.DoEvents()
            End While

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

A child form is created that processes an action based on the path and file name.
until the loop is complete, the folder the files were dragged from is locked.

How would I get a list of the path and file names AND process each one without locking out the source folder?

(I'm using the while loop to process the file names sequentially, pausing between each one while maintaining UI response)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try processing the files after the drag&drop event by calling `BeginInvoke` in the handler.